# PHP executes code after echo before finishing echo code

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('test') != -1) {
    }
    else
        window.open('http://google.com', '_parent', ''); 
    </script>";
echo "test";
```

The code executes successfully **BUT** if it will open `http://google.com` using `window.open` it still shows `echo "test"` before successfully redirecting to google.com.

Can I somehow prevent executing code after the else statement in the javascript (`window.open('http://google.com', '_parent', '');`)?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Does that seem that I just ask to ask? I thought that something might exist that I could use in javascript to stop browser from printing echo "test" if I reached else statement in javascript code.

Comment: Why you put you code after it, if you don't want to execute it?

Comment: You are giving the browser extra stuff to parse and render. I don't think you have control over the way the browser does that. Is it possible to simply remove the echo?

Comment: Because if I pass ?test=something as a parameter that means that I do not want to redirect and execute code under the echo with javascript. In our paradigm:  `echo "test"`

Comment: did you ask this question just to ask something? no offence but c'mon... ;p

Comment: Does that seem that I just ask to ask? I thought that something might exist that I could use in javascript to stop browser from printing `echo "test"` if I reached else statement in javascript code.

Comment: If your question is "Can I somehow prevent executing code after the else statement in the javascript" then my answer is comment that line :P practical joke, but its browser that's doing it, don't blame PHP, purists already hate PHP. On a serious note, what actually you want to achieve will help others understand and then come one can propose a solution.

Comment: You're getting things wrong..it's not that php executes the echo BEFORE finishing the other, it's executing it BECAUSE it finished the other. The JS gets all printed on html (php has already done all his job here), you see 'test' because the browser doesn't redirect instantaniously, and 'test' is already wrote in there.

Comment: @Kumar: That's why I cannot understand why someone can vote this question -1 or believe that this is a stupid question. Common guys!

Comment: @Immo php runs on the server, by the time the html is rendered php's job is done. You can't prevent through JS the second echo to be printed, if you want that you need to do it at server level, not client level

Comment: @Damie Pirsy: I understood that. My question was if there is way to OVERCOME this limitation!

Comment: **That's not a limitation!** PHP works (before) on the server, javascript (after) on the client. Separate worlds, and the second is a consequence of the first.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy : Yes mate. I am not saying that this is a limitation of PHP or anything. But I BELIEVE that when the browser reads the result of the php server request if for example finds a `window.open()` should wait some seconds before printing the rest of the code. That is what I was suggesting and what I believed that I would achieve.But it seems that this is not possible!

Comment: It's not possibile because the html is not generated along the way, but one time, after the php has been parsed and has spat out it's result. When php finishes, html is made. Not generated step by step, hope you get it now

Comment: @immo what I understand is you try to run some test in browser and if it fails you want the page to be sent to google w/out printing test. If somehow you can run your test at PHP side you can use headers to send the browser to Google w/out printing any thing in browser, read http://php.net/headers and if possible state what actually you want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should understand this order.

1. PHP executes script and generate HTML/JS/etc
2. Then browser get it, parse and execute.

So you should use any of php condition to avoid printing "test" in some cases

Comment: @Immo In this case you can use if(isset($_GET['test'])) print 'test' else print 'other code';